# Converting a curl command to Ajax, what is -i -u "clientId:"?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, curl

I'm currently trying to integrate a 3rd party API into my website, I am testing the API using Postman (the Chrome Extension) before writing my AngularJS Service (using `$http`). However I am unsure about one thing. Here is the original curl command provided by the API documentation (I have modified the URL)

```
curl -i -u "{clientId}:" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET "https://api.thirdparty.com/api/rest/functionality"
```

Now it's all very simple. I make a get request to the URL and I add the header `"Content-Type: application/json"`. However what do I do for the command `-i -u "{clientId}:"`? Obviously I have to send this in the header, but I don't know if I am expected to just add another header like `"{clientId}:{clientId}"` or if I have to pass something different as I am ussure what the `-i and -u`?

Please note that {clientId} is just a placeholder for a real clientId like '1qw43Q', etc...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about jQuery ajax function, which I think you do, you need add this to you ajax call.

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" +        password));
}
```

For details see here
[How to use Basic Auth with jQuery and AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507234/how-to-use-basic-auth-with-jquery-and-ajax)